# how can i send mail with out composer splash screen

Tags: iphone

i need to send mail in my application.

for that my code is,

```
MFMailComposeViewController * mailView = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
 [mailView setMailComposeDelegate:self];  
 [mailView setSubject:@"Some Subject"];
 [mailView setToRecipients:self.selectedArray];
 [self presentModalViewController:mailView animated:YES];
 [mailView release];  

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {

 [controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

for that i am getting the splash screen [like this](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e2fbf214c6.gif).

is it possible to send mail without this splash screen.

i need to send mail in background.

can any one please suggest me.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't want to use the composer you have to write your own smtp client. 
I've never tried it but from what I've heard [skpsmtpmessage](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/) should do the trick.

Comment: The other problem with this approach is that you either have to ask the user for an email address and password or provide an email account and password within the app that will do the sending. *At least I think that's the case...*

Comment: Thank q u fluchtpunkt,but i found more comment on that,that most of the people getting problems using this.Is there any alternate way

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, wouldn't the user have to provide his e-mail ID and password to send mail using this approach? This would be additional overhead and the user may choose not to do the mail setup(assuming mail application of device is configured) again.